# how to write String array in a csv column

Tags: java, file, csv, supercsv

```
public class bean {
  private String name;
  private String[] friends;
}

public void createSuperCSVFile(final List<VariantTO> data,
                               final File file) throws IOException {
    ICsvBeanWriter beanWriter = null;
    try {
        String[] header = {"name", "friends"};
        beanWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter(file), TAB_PREFERENCE);
        // write the header
        beanWriter.writeHeader(header);

        for (Object object: data) {
            beanWriter.write(object, header);
        }
    } finally {
        if( beanWriter != null ) {
            beanWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using supercsv to write a POJO with an attribute containing string array to csv. The CsvBeanWriter simply writes the object address instead of its value in the column. Is there any settings to map the value correctly?

```
EXPECTED
name    friends
john    dimitry,olaf,nett

ACTUAL
name    friends
john    [Ljava.lang.String;@50ccb5a3
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to write my own cell processor. I wrote a String[] processor, which returns a comma separated value as a string.

```
final CellProcessor[] PROCESSORS = new CellProcessor[] {
    new NotNull(),
    new ParseStringArray()
};

beanWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter(file), TAB_PREFERENCE);

for (Object object: data) {
    beanWriter.write(object, header, PROCESSORS);
}


class ParseStringArray extends CellProcessorAdaptor implements StringCellProcessor {
    @Override
    public <T> T execute(final Object value, final CsvContext context) {
        validateInputNotNull(value, context);
        String result;
        if (value instanceof String[]) {
            result = StringUtils.join((String[]) value, ",");
        } else {
            final String actualClassName = value.getClass().getName();
            throw new SuperCsvCellProcessorException(String.format(
                "the input value should be of type String array but is of type %s", actualClassName), context, this);
        }

        return next.execute(result, context);
    }
}
```